# Is there a way to hide window properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend, development-environment

I ran across a website today, http://www.riverfronttimes.com/, I found something very interesting about it that boggled my mind. I had to ask you guys about it.

What was interesting was that I couldn't get window height and width properties on it. For example:

```
$(window).width();
$(window).height();
```

I kept getting an error:

```
VM1733:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).width is not a function(…)
```

Why am I getting this, are the properties hidden? Can I do this for my websites? 
Is there anything advantageous about this?

I've even tried using pure javascript but couldn't get the height and width.

It's got me so curious.

Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assuming the `$` available on that page is jQuery but it isn't. If it were, you could do `$.fn.jquery` from the console and get a version.

While they do have jQuery loaded on the page, `$` isn't bound to it. This can be seen by entering `$ === jQuery` which returns `false`. Normally, it'd return `true`.

If you want to use their jQuery, you could do something like:

```js
jQuery(window).width();
```

Comment: I see, I typed jQuery.length and because I saw that and other jQuery methods I use, I did assume that it was jQuery attached to $. At the same time, jQuery.height and width are not there.

Comment: @nyhunter77 The jQuery functions that operate on jQuery collections are under `jQuery.fn` rather than just `jQuery`.

Comment: Ah yes! I didn't remember that. Thanks for the reminder. *bonk* hitting my head.  jQuery(window).width() works fine. I am writing a bit of code that has to check for window width, I think this way with jQuery instead of $ would cover more bases. - With pure JS, window.innerWidth; I'm guessing this would cover even more but there seems to be 15px difference between them. It shouldn't matter much but would you happen to know why that is? Thanks!

Comment: @nyhunter77 Could be the scrollbar. `window.innerwidth` doesn't include it but `$(window).width()` might.

Comment: Thanks again, i think it's the other way around. Appreciate the great info